# creating an array that does specific outputs according to Choices

Tags: arrays, swift

I have songs which are french and Chinese with different difficulty levels such as easy medium and advanced.

I was trying to create an array. I first made a prototype to test it:

```
var array = [[["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"],["g","h","i"]],[["j","k","l"],["m","n","o"], ["p","q","r"]]]

print(array[1][0])

/*prints j, k, l

index[0] is Chinese songs
index[1] is french songs

index[0][1]= Chinese songs with medium level 
index[1][2]=  French songs with Hard level
index[0][0]= Chinese songs with beginner level*/
```

I tried to use the same principle in my current program but I failed. I think I will manage it If I can successfully implement it into an array.I also tried dictionaries but I couldn't manage to do it.Since I have objects such as name, lyrics, mp3type etc within the array that made it diffucult.

My code works perfectly when you want to put all the songs and append it but I want to customise the song choice to the user's choices.So when they click Chinese beginner level only Chinese and beginner level array should pass on to the music player.

```
arrSong.append(SongModel(name: "Cold Water", lyrics: "Everybody.." 
path: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ColdWater", ofType: "m4a")!))
```

This is just a prototype song list. I am just trying to figure how to do solve this problem.i also referenced some code related to my project so Maybe it can make more sense.

```
func setUI(){

lbl_song_name.text = arrSong[currIndex].name
lbl_lyrics.numberOfLines = 0
lbl_lyrics.text = arrSong[currIndex].lyrics
{



func SongPlay(){

self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: 
arrSong[currIndex].path))

let asset = AVURLAsset(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: 
arrSong[currIndex].path)).duration
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best way forward would be to *not* have some complicated multi-dimensional array to search in but instead to have a struct or class with language (chinese/french) and difficulty as property and then use the built in filter functionality to find all songs that matches the user selection.

Example (simplified)

```
struct Song {
  var name: String
  var difficulty: Int //Enum is better here
  vae language: String
}

//Simple array with all songs
let allSongs: [Song]

//Filtering user selection
let userSelectedLevel = ... // from UI
let userSelectedLanguage = ...// from UI
let userSelection = allSongs.filter({$0.difficulty == userSelectedLevel && $0.language == userSelectedLAnguage})
```

The array userSelection will now contain the songs that matches the users choose and can now be used for further processing in the code.